# Change tmap legend from symbol based to fill based

Tags: r, tmap

I have a tmap with the following code:

```
  map <- tm_shape(gb_map)+tm_polygons(border.col = 'transparent', col='black')+
  tm_shape(data) +
    tm_dots("pred",palette="OrRd",
            style = "fisher",
            border.col='transparent', 
            title = "Predicted Sales",
            n=5, size =0.03) +
    tm_layout("Predicted Sales", title.size=1, legend.outside = T)
```

This is currently in tmap view mode.

I wish to change the legend such that the legend denotes the colours by squares because the symbol now is too small. Is there any way to keep everything the same but just change the legend to be square-based? (I can't increase the size of the symbol because I wish to have the dots appear small on the map) Manually adding the legend causes me to lose the break points which I prefer not to because I am using 'fisher' to determine the break points.

[image]

Possible to change to a legend like this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the legend as dots because you are using `tm_dots`. Use `tm_fill` instead will automatically give you square-based legend. Please provide some data so that I can try your code and suggest suitable measures. Before doing this, read your polygon data as

```
library("rgdal")
Output.Areas <-  readOGR(".", "shapefile_name")
```

Then read your data file

```
data <- read.csv("File_name.csv")
```

Now you join data to the shapefile

```
merged <- merge(Output.Areas, data, by.x="NAME_1", by.y="NAME_2")
```

Common field from data (NAME_2) and Output.Areas shapefile (NAME_1) are NAME_1 and NAME_2. 
Now `tm_fill` will automatically give you square-based legend as

```
tm_shape(merged)+
  tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
  tm_fill("pred",palette="OrRd",
          style = "fisher",
          title = "Predicted Sales")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too late to answer this questions. Neverthless, I think something like this is what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

Breaks <- c(0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 31000)
Labels <- c("0 - 2000", "2000 - 4000", "4000 - 6000", ">6000")

tm_shape(nc) + 
 tm_polygons(col="BIR79", title = "Births 1979 - 84", palette = "YlGnBu",
                       breaks = Breaks, labels = Labels) + 
tm_layout(legend.position = c(0.01,0.65),
          scale=0.65,
          legend.frame = T,
          bg.color = "lightblue") + 
tm_compass(size = 5, type = "rose", lwd = 3) + 
tm_scale_bar(breaks = c(0,50,100,150,200),size = 1, position = c(0.06,0),
             lwd = 3)
```